# Visual Studio install project doesn't perform InstallConditions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-installer, registry

I'm creating an installer for a C# application using Visual Studio Install Project. This application needs Python, so I added this as custom prerequisite. 
This is the package manifest I wrote for the prerequisite:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package Name="DisplayName" Culture="Culture"    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
<PackageFile Name="python-3.4.4.amd64.msi" HomeSite="https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/python-3.4.4.amd64.msi"    PublicKey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
</PackageFiles>
<InstallChecks>
<RegistryCheck Property="IsInstalled" Key="HKLM\Software\Python\"/>
<RegistryCheck Property="IsCurrentUserInstalled" Key="HKCU\Software\Python\"/>
</InstallChecks>
<Commands Reboot="Defer">
<Command PackageFile="python-3.4.4.amd64.msi">
  <InstallConditions>
    <BypassIf Property="IsInstalled" Compare="ValueExists" />
    <BypassIf Property="IsCurrentUserInstalled" Compare="ValueExists" />
  </InstallConditions>
  <ExitCodes>
    <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
    <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
   </ExitCodes>
 </Command>
</Commands>
<Strings>
<String Name="Culture">no</String>
<String Name="DisplayName">Python 3.4.4</String>
<String Name="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr">An unexpected exit code was returned from the installer. The installation failed.</String>
</Strings>
</Package>
```

The problem is that when I run the installer on a system which has Python, it keeps me asking to download and install it. The registry keys I look for are present on the system. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me whether the bootstrapper check is looking in the native or WoW6432 location. If it's a 32-bit app it might be looking in the wrong (i.e. the 32-bit) registry. I don't know if there is a way to choose the WoW6432 registry or the native one.

Also, from looking in the Registry table in the Python MSI file, it does not appear to write anything containing "IsInstalled", and I'd expect the install to be the thing that created that entry. 
There is however a Software\Python\PythonCore\3.4\InstallPath entry that contains the install location, so maybe that's something else to look for.

Comment: IsInstalled is just a variable name for the RegistryCheck: it should be true if the registry key HKLM\Software\Python exists. Same thing for IsCurrentUserInstalled. Now I see that the problem is that the checks are performed after downloading Python: if it's already installed, it downloads it anyway but doesn't require to install it.